# How can I debug SIGSEV in operator new on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, debugging

I have a case where my application crashes in operator new with SIGSEV when the a certan user action is performed.

- It's repeatable for a certain action but it doesn't always crash when the user performs the particular actoin, perhaps crash 20% of the times the action is performed.
- The application is written in C++14 and uses Qt for GUI. Can be built for both Linux and Windows
- The problem exists only on Linux
- valgrind has not revealed any memory issues

The call stack shows

```
tcache_get
__GI__libc_malloc
operator new(unsigned long)
x = new myobject(arg);
```

Anyone one that can give a hint on how to identify the issue?

Comment: Try all the sanitizers: ASAN, ASAN+UBSAN, TSAN...

Comment: Unfortunately there is no paint-by-numbers, cookie-cutter set of instructions that only needs to be followed in order to identify the root cause. Valgrind cannot catch all possible causes of memory corruption.

Comment: The error is somewhere else and happened before the program came to this `new myobject(arg)`. Try valgrind.

Comment: You can try and replace `operator new` and `operator delete` with something that uses some kind of debugging allocator library (like de-alloc), but if valgrind doesn't see the problem there is not a lot of chances a debugging allocator will help. Still there are some. You will probably need to run a heap consistency check every now and then.